# Drawable state not staying "pressed"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this list of states set up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello_pressed"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/hello"
        />
</selector>
```

But when I click on the element, the drawable doesn't stay "pressed". It changes to "pressed" and then when I let go it reverts back to the normal drawable.

How do I keep it pressed after I press the element?

Comment: This is the expected behavior. You might try `android:state_activated` but not sure. Or, depending on what you've got going on, you might want a compound button and use `state_checked`

Comment: Use a custom CheckBox or a custom ToggleButton (or Switch) instead of your current View. These ones retain their "pressed" state.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to this is from code...

```
boolean isPressed = false;    

//click event on your control
public void OnClick(View v) {
if (!isPressed)
   yourControl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hello_pressed);
else yourControl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hello);

isPressed = !isPressed;
}
```

Comment: Where would `onClick()` go?